# how to set order of custom post type term and post's

Tags: wordpress

hello guys i am using custom post type for showing plans. I want to customise the  order of term and it's post for that i am using below code

```
<?php
    $plan_group = get_terms('numbers_plans', array(
        'orderby' => 'description',  //this is for term order it's working
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ));
    foreach ( $plan_group as $plan_group_term ) {
          $plan_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'numbers_plan',
                'tax_query' => array(
                     array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'numbers_plans',
                          'field'    => 'slug',
                          'terms'    => array( $plan_group_term->slug )
                       )                                
                    )
                ));
 ?>
```

anyone please tell me how can i set order of my post's.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys i had done it below code is working for me!!

```
<?php
    $plan_group = get_terms('numbers_plans', array(
        'orderby' => 'description',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ));
    foreach ( $plan_group as $plan_group_term ) {
        $plan_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'numbers_plan',
            'meta_key'  => 'plan_minutes',
            'orderby'   => '0',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'numbers_plans',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $plan_group_term->slug )
                )
            )
        ));
    ?>
```